# Looking for a tool to create a media server for my company

Tags: image, video, upload, media, transcoding

Looking for a tool, hopefully open-source or a free edition that will allow for:

- Image Upload
- Video Upload
- Accounts with permissions so certain
  accounts can view specific folders of
  images or videos
- A Gallery to display images and
  videos and hopefully include HTML
  embed code
- Be able to tag items uploaded so they may be searched

Those are my basic needs.  I have tried Kaltura, but it's not quite what I am looking for, it focuses too much on video and not enough on images.  Plus a couple of other things that didn't suit me needs.
Any ideas?  I would like to run it on an openSUSE 11.X install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not anything out there exactly like that.  While I have heard similar requests before, everyone has their own take on how it should work and what the features should be.

The closes thing I can think of that might suite your needs is [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/features) with a module like [embedVideo](http://codex.gallery2.org/Gallery2%3aModules%3aembedvideo).  Regardless, it very well may require a bit of coding on your part to flesh out everything you desire.

This all could run on openSUSE, no problem.